# Redirect to specific IdP in Azure ACS

Tags: .net, azure, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity, acs

I'm developing a 4.5 .NET web app that has ADFS and ACS as Providers Trust.

I redirect users depending on the URL that they type to ADFS or to ACS for authentication.

I have two Office 365 Identity Providers in the ACS.

I use `e.SignInRequestMessage.HomeRealm = "https://myACSname.accesscontrol.windows.net/"`
in the event `WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider` to redirect to the ACS login page.

But I would like to be able to redirect directly to the specific O365 identity provider, so customers don't see other customer's IdP names (that's what happens when there is only one IdP per ACS)

I have been testing with the URLS as:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/e879e477-7763-xxxxx-xxxx

https://sts.windows.net/49e568989-089e-4bdd-ac8c-xxx

https://myACSname.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2ffs.myDomain.com%2fadfs%2fservices%2ftrust&wctx=2a86695-6f3f-409b-a050-0a34c3ca3621&wct=2015-11-05T12%3a05%3a05Z&whr=https%3a%2+f%myDomain.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f

But none of them work.

If possible, how to set up the **whr** parameter for this?

Comment: I ended up by creating one ACS with one IdP per customer using O365, but will leave the question open waiting for real answers to the question.